# Microsoft Cognitive speech services - Speech to text batch transcription permission error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

Hello!
I am trying to use MS cognitive services for speech to text transcription. I need to run a sample first before I build it into my production app though. So I am trying out this: [Git sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/batch/csharp)

This sample basically just asks you to fill in the host name, subscription key and the Azure blob URL. I have done all of that and I am able to get the JWT token and read what files I have uploaded so far(0 actually). 
Just that when I try to upload a file for transcription it gives me this in response:

```
InnerException  {"Only \"Standard\" subscriptions for the region of the called service are valid."} System.Exception {BatchClient.FailedHttpClientRequestException}
```

So, are trial users not allowed to use the service?
Is there a API within MS cognitive services which supports trial users so that we can try out the service before buying?
I have tried to run through their docs but it is not clear what all options I might have in this context.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4):

The Batch API, which you are trying to use, can only be used with a paid "Standard" subscription key as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription). The real-time APIs (all the other samples [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples)) can be evaluated using the subscription from the free tier.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same code sample and it worked for me.

Following things to notice:

1)  I have tried **\samples\csharp\dotnetcore\console** c# sample for the scenario reproduction.

2) I have tried Translation service and speech to text using microphone which was there in option no 1 and 5.

[image]

3) Please make sure to modify the subscription key and service region of your cognitive service api.
in my case it was west us which i got it from below portal.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/my-apis/?apiSlug=speech-services

Endpoint was   **https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0**

4) For using microphone , please change the subscription key and service region in belo class.

**RecognitionWithMicrophoneAsync.cs**

Here is the output for the same

[image]

Let me know if you need any help.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can not use this sample. Even when I use non batch API: https://westeurope.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US which only accepts wav files I get same error. I have files in wav and mp3 format that need transcription. I am afraid what @user1248490 is saying is correct. There is no way a free user can use the service.

Comment: Understood, let me know if you need any other help related to Azure or cognitive services.

Comment: thanks! Which API version should i be using? V1 or V2? I want to transcribe audio files and eventually I want to make a live transcription via web sockets or something similar when a call is on going on my web app.